# debugging linker errors (undefined symbols)

Tags: c

I'm trying to link an executable with an external library called [libr](http://www.radare.org/y/). I'm not looking for help with that library specifically, only the linker error, which is pasted below:

```
undefined reference to `r_asm_new()'
```

Ok, so I double check my link command:

```
-lr_core -lr_config -lr_cons -lr_cmd -lr_util -lr_flags -lr_asm -lr_lib -lr_debug -lr_hash -lr_bin -lr_lang -lr_io -lr_anal -lr_parse -lr_bp -lr_egg -lr_reg -lr_search -lr_syscall -lr_sign -lr_diff -lr_socket -lr_fs -lr_magic -lr_db
```

and it seems to contain all the libraries that libr package has. I double the the libr_asm.so file with objdump:

```
$ objdump -T libr_asm.so.0.9.3git | grep r_asm_new
  00000000000ca66a g    DF .text    0000000000000149  Base        r_asm_new
```

so as far as I can tell the -l_asm flag should have done it. I'm linking a c library to a c++ executable, but I can't think of how that could change the situation.

Thanks.

EDIT:
The full link line:

```
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cc.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/ElfFile.cc.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/ElfFileSection.cc.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/ElfFileDefinitions.cc.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/SectionsWindow.cc.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/SectionView.cc.o  -o main -rdynamic -L/home/chris/radare_install/lib -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_system-mt -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgtksourceviewmm-3.0 -lgtkmm-3.0 -lgtksourceview-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lr_core -lr_config -lr_cons -lr_cmd -lr_util -lr_flags -lr_lib -lr_debug -lr_hash -lr_bin -lr_lang -lr_io -lr_anal -lr_parse -lr_bp -lr_egg -lr_reg -lr_search -lr_syscall -lr_sign -lr_diff -lr_socket -lr_fs -lr_magic -lr_db -lr_asm -Wl,-rpath,/home/chris/radare_install/lib
```

Comment: Have you tried (a) ensuring your lib list is the *last* thing on your link-line, and (b) moving your `-lr_asm` to the *end* of that list? (or beginning, I can never remember which). But for sure, the list *must* be *after* your .cpp files and -o target file.

Comment: yup, though I've never seen that make a difference.

Comment: Maybe your toolchain adds some name decoration and is actually looking for "__r_asm_new()" or someting of the sort ?

Comment: The file/library defining a function must be after the files and libraries that use the function, so the order matters.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly, some linkers, particularly of the gcc-persuasion, are just that finicky.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think it's the way Unix `ld` has always worked.

Comment: @Barmar shows how much I use `ld`. Gotta remember that. I've written enough makefiles, but I always put the libs on the end as a matter of style, not necessity. It wasn't till I came here I found it was the right thing to do all along.

Comment: @WhozCraig You also need to worry about the order among the libs, if there are dependencies among them.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, that much I *did* figure out after trial and error (and a lot of googling).

Answer (score 4):

....the comments on this question reminded me:

```
extern "C" {
  #include "foo.h"
}
```